# How can I make GNU debugger gdb attach to a daemon when it starts/restarts?

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging

I have a daemon (say tempd) running and gdb is attached to it.

```
% ps x | grep tempd
5467  ??  S      0:00.36 /usr/sbin/tmpd -N

> gdb
gdb> symbol-file /var/tmp/tmpd
gdb> attach 5467
gdb> breakpoint a_funcion_name
breakpoint was set 
gdb> c 
continuing
.
```

How can make gdb to automatically attach to the new PID when the daemon restarts? I want to set the breakpoint at a function which gets executed before I find the daemon's new PID and attach gdb to it manually. I do not have the option to start the daemon from within gdb, as it is triggered by an event.

Comment: This seems to be more relevant to [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). Try to ask there

Answer (score 0):

Is it your own daemon? If so, can start gdb from within the daemon?

```
system( "xterm -c gdb <prog-path> <pid> &");
```

should do the trick. Maybe add a sleep afterwards to give xterm/gdb time to come up.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another script, that check's constantly or in an inerval
If a process named x is created
Then execute gdb and attach to it.